# Windows 7, Black screen with cursor, impossible to logon

Tags: windows-7, boot, black-screen-of-death

First - I have gone through as many possible solutions I've found here and elsewhere.

[Edit - to describe the issue in more detail, the PC appears to boot correctly, but instead of the logon screen, I have been getting a black screen *WITH* the pointer cursor, and it responds correctly to the mouse. Pressing CTL-ALT-DEL brings up the logon screen's background, but with no logon area nor any other content.  This screen was at the full resolution before I uninstalled the graphics driver in safe-mode.]

I also just ran a full up-to-date AVG scan from boot media.

[Edit - the AVG scan, which was updated to today's virus signatures, found no issues at all.]

So - steps I've tried:

1. Safe Boot, Restore from before the issue - done, no help.
2. Uninstall the graphics driver - done, now i have a 1024x768 fallback screen, still no way in.
3. sfc /scannow - only doable from Safe boot obviously, but no change.
4. [Edit - booting from restore media, performing a startup repair and...]Restore further back - restored to 2 days ago, and I'd had many reboots since then with no problem.
5. Enable autologin to try to get beyond the login screen - done, doesn't work.

It seems the best advice is complete reinstall, but I really don't want to do that because it'll take 3-4 days to add all the apps I use.

Some key points to note - in both states - before and after removing the video driver, I always had a mouse cursor on the screen.   CTL-ALT-DEL flashes up the login background, but no login info.

I *can* (and often do) reinstall from scratch, but was at a fairly stable state before this, and would prefer not to.

-Paul

Comment: I assume you have removed the video driver completly.

Comment: @ramhound yes, and when i do boot fully back I'm now in fallback 1024x768, with exactly the same behaviour - ie black screen, with cursor, ctl-alt-del temporarily brings up the login screen background.

Comment: Have you tried to boot with a Widows 7 disc to do a repair?

Comment: @CharlieRB - yes - I should amend the question - the second rollback was from boot media, and after a startup repair.

Comment: can you bring up task manager with ctrl+shift+esc?

Comment: @BroScience - nope - on the black screen (with mouse pointer, which works), CTL-ALT-DEL brings up the logon background temporarily, CTL-SHIFT-ESC does nothing.  Also tried CTL-SHIFT-ESC during the time the background is up, and still nothing.  Mouse still works :(

Comment: Have you tried to `chkdsk` the system drive?

Comment: @PJC, I would recommend try [uninstall AVG](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlname=How-to-uninstall-AVG) & see

Comment: Since you've determined that you don't suspect malicious software at hand, enabling Administrator Command Prompt may prove helpful. Several password crackers, KonBoot being my favorite, have built-in features where cmd with the highest privileges can be accessed with sticky keys after booting. If you don't currently have access to Administrative privileges, this could help.

Comment: Can the mouse cursor move off the edge of the screen? It sounds almost like there's a "virtual" monitor that is being marked as primary and the login and ctrl+alt+del  content show up there instead of on your actual monitor

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your Credential Providers got messed up. If you're able to boot your system into safe mode, please open the registry editor and navigate to this registry path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers
```

You'll see subpaths in GUID format which are all Credential Providers that are available on your system.

Please check each path if it contains a REG_DWORD value named `Disabled` and if so, delete this value. On my system there is only one credential provider that is deactivated which is the PINLogonProvider value with the data:

```
{cb82ea12-9f71-446d-89e1-8d0924e1256e}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like something has corrupted user permissions/account. I have never actually seen this on a system that was working before but this link looks promising:
http://www.sevenforums.com/crashes-debugging/27414-blank-screen-cursor-but-no-log-screen.html

Comment: Already tried everything on that thread with no joy, plus note this PC has been running happily for over a year.